# Facebook-like selection

Tags: facebook, select, autocomplete

I have made [this Facebook-like selection](http://ajaxdump.com/?jGTEq2fo) in which the selection can be unselected by clicking the `x` button. I already got my `Auto-complete` working but I only want to have the selected options to look like the one on the link. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The source code for FCBKcomplete can be found here:
http://www.emposha.com/javascript/fcbkcomplete.html

It's basically a list (UL) with styled list items.

```
/* Copyright: Guillermo Rauch <http://devthought.com/> - Distributed under MIT - Keep this message! */

/* TextboxList sample CSS */
ul.holder { margin: 0; border: 1px solid #999; overflow: hidden; height: auto !important; height: 1%; padding: 4px 5px 0; }
*:first-child+html ul.holder { padding-bottom: 2px; } * html ul.holder { padding-bottom: 2px; } /* ie7 and below */
ul.holder li { float: left; list-style-type: none; margin: 0 5px 4px 0; white-space:nowrap;}
ul.holder li.bit-box, ul.holder li.bit-input input { font: 11px "Lucida Grande", "Verdana"; }
ul.holder li.bit-box { -moz-border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px; border: 1px solid #CAD8F3; background: #DEE7F8; padding: 1px 5px 2px; }
ul.holder li.bit-box-focus { border-color: #598BEC; background: #598BEC; color: #fff; }
ul.holder li.bit-input input { width: auto; overflow:visible; margin: 0; border: 0px; outline: 0; padding: 3px 0px 2px; } /* no left/right padding here please */
ul.holder li.bit-input input.smallinput { width: 20px; }

/* Facebook demo CSS */
ul.holder { margin: 0 !important }
ul.holder li.bit-box, #apple-list ul.holder li.bit-box { padding-right: 15px; position: relative; z-index:1000;}
#apple-list ul.holder li.bit-input { margin: 0; }
#apple-list ul.holder li.bit-input input.smallinput { width: 5px; }
ul.holder li.bit-hover { background: #BBCEF1; border: 1px solid #6D95E0; }
ul.holder li.bit-box-focus { border-color: #598BEC; background: #598BEC; color: #fff; }
ul.holder li.bit-box a.closebutton { position: absolute; right: 4px; top: 5px; display: block; width: 7px; height: 7px; font-size: 1px; background: url('close.gif'); }
ul.holder li.bit-box a.closebutton:hover { background-position: 7px; }
ul.holder li.bit-box-focus a.closebutton, ul.holder li.bit-box-focus a.closebutton:hover { background-position: bottom; }

/* Autocompleter */

.facebook-auto { display: none; position: absolute; background: #eee; z-index:1001;}
.facebook-auto .select_all_items {display: block; float: right;}
.facebook-auto .default { padding: 5px 7px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-width: 0 1px 1px;font-family:"Lucida Grande","Verdana"; font-size:11px; }
.facebook-auto ul { display: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: auto; position:absolute; z-index:9999}
.facebook-auto ul li { padding: 5px 12px; z-index: 1000; cursor: pointer; margin: 0; list-style-type: none; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-width: 0 1px 1px; font: 11px "Lucida Grande", "Verdana"; background-color: #eee }
.facebook-auto ul li em { font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; background: #ccc; }
.facebook-auto ul li.auto-focus { background: #4173CC; color: #fff; }
.facebook-auto ul li.auto-focus em { background: none; }
.deleted { background-color:#4173CC !important; color:#ffffff !important;}
.hidden { display:none;}

#demo ul.holder li.bit-input input { padding: 2px 0 1px; border: 1px solid #999; }
.ie6fix {height:1px;width:1px; position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:1;}
```

Comment: I was hoping to read the right answer though I already solved it, maybe because it was my fault not clearly elaborating my query. Anyway thanks for this Sir. :)